# Setting values for mat multiple select options with string values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have mat multiple select options that have options with `String` values. The issue is when I try to set values for those options, It's only pre-selects the first option of each selected element.

Here is the screenshot for that:

[image]

The code for the select options is:

```
  <mat-form-field *ngFor="let submenu of selectedMenu.subMenuList;">
    <mat-label>{{ submenu.name }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select
      [compareWith]="compare"
      multiple
      [(ngModel)]="selectedValues[submenu.name]"
      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
      [maxlength]="submenu.noOfSelections"
      #selectCtrl="ngModel"
    >
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let ingredient of submenu.ingredients.trim().split(',')"
        [value]="ingredient"
        >{{ingredient}}</mat-option
      >
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="selectCtrl.hasError('maxlength')">
      Maximum {{ submenu.noOfSelections }} selection(s) allowed.
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

This is the code in the `TS` file that I'm trying to set user-selected values for the select elements. Here, the initial `menuDetails` is a single-string object. I put those string values to the `selectedValues` object which use to give values to the selected elements. Anyway `menuName` form control giving the correct value which I `setValue` at the end of the `setSelectedMenu()` in the `TS` file

```
setSelectedMenu() {
const keyValuePairs: string[] = this.data.menuDetails.split(';');

keyValuePairs.forEach((pair) => {
  const [key, valuesString] = pair.split(':');
  const values = valuesString
    .trim()
    .split(',')
    .map((value) => value.trim());
  this.selectedValues[key.trim()] = values;
});

let menuName: string = this.selectedValues['menuName'][0].trim();

// Getting menu object to set for the select menu
this.selectedMenu = this.menus.find((m) => {
  return m.name.trim() === menuName.trim();
});

this.form.controls['menuName'].setValue(this.selectedMenu);
}
```

I've been trying to figure out this issue for two days but still can't find a solution. Any help is appreciated.